# iOS / JavaScript / Phonegap

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I'm porting an Android app to iOS with Phonegap but I have a problem. In the app I use openstreet map, I take tiles from a folder in android in this way

```
L.tileLayer('file:///android_asset/www/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
```

What type of path should I use in iOS? The www folder is inside the main project folder. (example: HelloWorld/www)

thanks

Comment: I think you can just use a relative URL. If you have `/tiles/` folder inside your `/www/` folder, you can just link to those files like `<img src="./tiles/x/y/z.png">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:

```
 L.tileLayer('tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

If relative paths don't work (as MBillau suggested in his comment), you can get the absolute path of your current page and manipulate the string to point exactly to the png you need.

For example

```
var myLocation = window.location.href;
```

will point to something like "file:///var/mobile/Applications/23423423-ASDAE-9180-B8ASDFAS23508/NameOfApp.app/www/index.html"

You can use javascript substring methods to get the root url and append the tile file location you need.

```
var baseLocation = myLocation.substring(0, myLocation.length - 10);//removes index.html from end of string
var tileLocation = baseLocation + "tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png";
L.tileLayer(tileLocation);
```